# Probability mass function notation

Tags: probability

I'd like to know how to *read* the notation used on the LHS of the following **probability mass function**:

$$P(i|a,b) = \frac{1}{b-a+1}, a \le i \le b$$

Comment: I have just added the RHS of the equation. This is an equation for "uniform integer distribution".

Comment: Is it "for every i in [a, b]?

Comment: I would start out with something like the probabilty of $i$ given … but then it gets complicated: It seems to be given that $i$ is in $\{a,a+1,\ldots,b\}$, but that's awfully hard to read. Anyhow the vertical bar in that position is typically read as “given”, as in a conditional probability.

Comment: Here's a [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_int_distribution/) to the document containing the formula.